# Как сохранить изображение в C++ (библиотека stbi_image)?

Tags: c++, изображения

Изображение сохраняется не верно (оно вообще не должно меняться).
Видимо функция stbi_write_bmp последним параметром ожидает массив из unsigned char.
А как сделать чтобы работало с массивом из float?

(Может для таких случаев в stbi_image есть готовый инструментарий для конвертации float* пикселей в unsgined char* ?)

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION 1
#include <stb_image.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION 1
#include <stb_image_write.h>

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    const char*file="test.bmp";
    if(argc>1)file=argv[1];
    
    int w;
    int h;
    int c;
    float*pix=stbi_loadf(file,&w,&h,0,3);

    stbi_write_bmp(file,w,h,3,pix);//???

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: .bmp файлы же обычно содержат данные 8 бит на канал и сохранять туда `float` без потерь не получится в принципе.

Comment: пускай с потерями, у меня задача простая, я прочитал из файла->поработал с пикселями->вернул в файл